# Longtable stopped working + Random line at the top of my tables

Tags: longtable

Sorry if my wording isn't right, I'm not a native English speaker.

I have no idea what changed because I was not paying attention to that part of my document for a while but there seems to be a weird line that appears at the top of all my longtable tables, as well as making them stop working as longtable (they seem to never break, and "pagebreak" or "newpage" don't do anything.

[image: Image showing the top of the table with weird random line that wasn't there before]

I'm new with using LaTeX, I have used https://www.tablesgenerator.com/ for this.

Does anyone know how I might make it work again? Many thanks in advance :)

Here is a working code.

````
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib} %Nouvelles biblios
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float} % figer tableaux et graphs
\usepackage{setspace} %Gestion des interlignes
\usepackage{graphicx} %Gestion des images
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{longtable} %Grands tableaux
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{tablefootnote} %ndbp dans tableaux
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry} %Gestion des marges
\usepackage{array} %pour la gestion des tailles des tableaux
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url} %Gestion des URL
\usepackage{hyperref} %Gestion des URL


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption[Descripteurs du CARAP : Les savoirs liés à la langue]{Les savoirs liés à la langue} 
  \begin{longtable}[h]{|ll|}
    \label{tab:carap-savoirs}\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}La langue comme système sémiologique :\\ Connaitre quelques principes de fonctionnement des langues\end{tabular}}} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Savoir que la langue est constituée de signes qui forment\\ un système (approches   plurielles importantes)\end{tabular}} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Conceptualiser le\\ langage / l’écrit\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Savoir que le rapport entre les mots et leur référent / entre\\ le signifiant et le sens est a   priori arbitraire\\ (approches plurielles importantes)\end{tabular}} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Conceptualiser le\\ langage / l'écrit\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Savoir que le lien arbitraire entre le mot et le référent / entre\\ le signifiant et le sens est fixé, le plus souvent implicitement,\\ par convention au sein de la communauté linguistique\\ (approches plurielles importantes)\end{tabular}} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Conceptualiser le\\ langage / l’écrit\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Savoir que les langues fonctionnent selon des règles / normes\\ (approches plurielles utiles)\end{tabular}} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Conceptualiser le\\ langage / l’écrit\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Savoir qu’il existe toujours des variétés à l’intérieur de ce que\\ l’on désigne comme une même langue\end{tabular}} &
       \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Savoir qu’il existe des différences de fonctionnement entre\\ langage écrit et langage oral (approches plurielles utiles)\end{tabular}} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Conceptualiser\\ l’écrit\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Avoir des connaissances d’ordre linguistique sur une langue\\ particulière (la langue maternelle, la langue de l’école, les\\ langues étrangères, …)\end{tabular}} &
       \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Connaitre quelques principes de fonctionnement de la communication}} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Savoir qu’il existe d’autres formes de communication que\\ la communication linguistique (que la communication\\ linguistique n’est qu’une des formes possibles de la\\ communication)\end{tabular}} &
       \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Avoir des connaissances sur son propre répertoire\\ communicatif (langues et variétés, genres discursifs, formes\\ de communication…)\end{tabular}} &
       \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Savoir qu’il faut adapter son propre répertoire communicatif\\ au contexte social et culturel dans lequel la communication\\ se déroule\end{tabular}} &
       \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Savoir qu’il existe des moyens langagiers pour faciliter la\\ communication (simplification / reformulation / etc.\}\end{tabular}} &
       \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Savoir que la compétence à communiquer dont on dispose\\ repose sur des connaissances d’ordre linguistique, culturel\\ et social généralement implicites (approches plurielles\\ importantes)\end{tabular}} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Conceptualiser le\\ langage\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Savoir que le locuteur alloglotte possède, en lien avec sa\\ compétence plurilingue et pluriculturelle, un statut\\ particulier dans la communication\end{tabular}} &
       \\ \hline
   \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Savoir comment on acquiert / apprend une langue}} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Connaitre quelques principes généraux à propos de la\\ manière dont on apprend une langue (approches\\ plurielles utiles)\end{tabular}} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Stratégie\\ d’apprentissage\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Savoir que l’on peut s’appuyer sur les ressemblances\\ (structurelles / discursives / pragmatiques) entre les\\ langues pour apprendre des langues\end{tabular}} &
       \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Savoir que l’on peut mieux apprendre lorsqu’on a\\ une attitude d’acceptation vis-à-vis des différences\\ linguistiques (approches plurielles nécessaires)\end{tabular}} &
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Stratégie\\ d’apprentissage\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Savoir que la représentation qu’on a de la langue à\\ apprendre influence l’apprentissage\end{tabular}} &
       \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Savoir qu’il existe diverses stratégies d’apprentissage\\ des langues et qu’elles n’ont pas toutes la même\\ pertinence en fonction des buts visés\end{tabular}} &
       \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Savoir qu’il est utile de bien connaitre les stratégies\\ que l’on utilise afin de les adapter à ses buts\end{tabular}} &
       \\ \hline
  \end{longtable}
\end{figure}

\end{document}```
````

Comment: do not put a longtable inside a figure environment.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm pretty sure it used to work within the figure environment? I am using it so both my table and figures follow the same numbering and TOF.

Comment: Remove the `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` statements, and place the `\caption` directive *after* `\begin{longtable}{|ll|}`.

Comment: longtable can never make a multipage table in a figure. also the extra line at the top is not "random" you have `\label{tab:carap-savoirs}\\ `  so a first line with just one cell that has no visible text.

Comment: Off-topic: `top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm,right=3cm` may be expressed more succinctly as `margin=3cm`.

Comment: The output of these online table generators is so ugly. Spend a couple of minutes to understand the basics, e.g. at https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-08 and you will be able to write much better code.

Comment: Right, thanks!
So how can I keep my "figures" numbering and only one List of Figures (no List of Tables) without the Figure environment please?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's what the "TableGenerator" website made, I figured it was weird but I don't feel super comfortable making it myself because I don't understand the documentation very well (it's really clear but I'm novice)

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't want to be offensive, I just have a lot of trouble making it work when it's all generated so I don't feel skilled enough to make it from scratch.

Comment: The trouble with using generated code is that it is _so_ much more complicated than needed (you could remove all the `multicolumn` and `tabular`) that it makes it almost impossible to answer questions such as yours which require debugging what the existing code is doing, and suggesting changes to it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for explaining. I understand. I will try to provide a better version of the code, I'm just not sure exactly what I can remove because if I try to only put the basic things like "text & text", it does not work anymore. It feels a little overwhelming to do it all by myself when there are so many parts of the code I don't understand (this is my PhD thesis so I'm also a little bit overwhelmed just by the fact that I'm writing it!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is sadly always the case, the code produced by tablegenerators.com is ugly, grotesquely opaque, and pretty much unmaintainable.

I strongly recommend you switch from a `longtable` to an `xltabular` setup, set the table's target width to `\textwidth`, allow automatic line breaking in both columns, and do away with all those interior `tabular` wrappers. I'd also do away with all vertical rules and use fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules.

I really don't understand why you would want to employ a `figure` environment here. News flash: It's a table, not a figure...

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
% I've commented out all `\usepackage' instructions that aren't needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{natbib} %Nouvelles biblios
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}

%\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{framed}
%\usepackage{eurosym}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
%\usepackage{float} % figer tableaux et graphs
%\usepackage{setspace} %Gestion des interlignes
%\usepackage{graphicx} %Gestion des images
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{longtable} %Grands tableaux
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{tablefootnote} %ndbp dans tableaux
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry} %Gestion des marges
\usepackage{array} %pour la gestion des tailles des tableaux
%\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
%
%\usepackage{xurl} %%% [hyphens]{url} %Gestion des URL
%\usepackage{hyperref} %Gestion des URL

% new code:
\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
 
% Make the first column have a usable width that's 
% three times that of the second column
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} L{1.5} L{0.5} @{}}
    \caption[Descripteurs du CARAP: Les savoirs liés à la langue]%
    {Les savoirs liés à la langue}
    \label{tab:carap-savoirs}
    
    \\ \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{La langue comme système sémiologique}}\\ 
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Connaitre quelques principes de fonctionnement des langues}} 
    \\ \midrule

    Savoir que la langue est constituée de signes qui forment un système (approches plurielles importantes)&
    Conceptualiser le langage\slash l’écrit 
    \\ \addlinespace
    Savoir que le rapport entre les mots et leur référent\slash entre le signifiant et le sens est a   priori arbitraire (approches plurielles importantes)&
    Conceptualiser le langage\slash l'écrit 
    \\ \addlinespace
    Savoir que le lien arbitraire entre le mot et le référent\slash entre le signifiant et le sens est fixé, le plus souvent implicitement, par convention au sein de la communauté linguistique (approches plurielles importantes)&
    Conceptualiser le langage\slash l’écrit 
    \\ \addlinespace
    Savoir que les langues fonctionnent selon des règles\slash normes (approches plurielles utiles)&
    Conceptualiser le langage\slash l’écrit 
    \\ \addlinespace
    Savoir qu’il existe toujours des variétés à l’intérieur de ce que l’on désigne comme une même langue& 
    \\ \addlinespace
    Savoir qu’il existe des différences de fonctionnement entre langage écrit et langage oral (approches plurielles utiles)&
    Conceptualiser l’écrit 
    \\ \addlinespace
    Avoir des connaissances d’ordre linguistique sur une langue particulière (la langue maternelle, la langue de l’école, les langues étrangères, \dots)&
    
    \\ \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Connaitre quelques principes de fonctionnement de la communication}} 
    \\ \midrule
    
    Savoir qu’il existe d’autres formes de communication que la communication linguistique (que la communication linguistique n’est qu’une des formes possibles de la communication)&
    \\ \addlinespace
    Avoir des connaissances sur son propre répertoire communicatif (langues et variétés, genres discursifs, formes de communication\dots)&
    \\ \addlinespace
    Savoir qu’il faut adapter son propre répertoire communicatif au contexte social et culturel dans lequel la communication se déroule&
    \\ \addlinespace
    Savoir qu’il existe des moyens langagiers pour faciliter la communication (simplification\slash reformulation\slash etc.\}&
    \\ \addlinespace
    Savoir que la compétence à communiquer dont on dispose repose sur des connaissances d’ordre linguistique, culturel et social généralement implicites (approches plurielles importantes)&
    Conceptualiser le langage 
    \\ \addlinespace
    Savoir que le locuteur alloglotte possède, en lien avec sa compétence plurilingue et pluriculturelle, un statut particulier dans la communication&
    
   \\ \midrule
   \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Savoir comment on acquiert\slash apprend une langue}} 
   \\ \midrule
   
   Connaitre quelques principes généraux à propos de la manière dont on apprend une langue (approches plurielles utiles)&
   Stratégie d’apprentissage 
   \\ \addlinespace
   Savoir que l’on peut s’appuyer sur les ressemblances (structurelles\slash discursives\slash pragmatiques) entre les langues pour apprendre des langues&
   \\ \addlinespace
   Savoir que l’on peut mieux apprendre lorsqu’on a une attitude d’acceptation vis-à-vis des différences linguistiques (approches plurielles nécessaires)&
   Stratégie d’apprentissage 
   \\ \addlinespace
   Savoir que la représentation qu’on a de la langue à apprendre influence l’apprentissage&
   \\ \addlinespace
   Savoir qu’il existe diverses stratégies d’apprentissage des langues et qu’elles n’ont pas toutes la même pertinence en fonction des buts visés&
   \\ \addlinespace
   Savoir qu’il est utile de bien connaitre les stratégies que l’on utilise afin de les adapter à ses buts&
   \\ \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! :) It is much more readable as is, than the code that was generated, indeed. Thank you for taking this time for me, that's really nice.

Can you please explain why XLtabular is better than longtable in this case?
I am asked to produce one TOC and one list of figures only (no list of tables) in my document, hence the fact I was using figure environment around these tables.

Comment: @ManonCha - The `xltabular` environment combines the strengths of the `longtable` and `tabularx` environments. E.g., an `xltabular` environment can contain page breaks (just as `longtable` can), and you can use the `X` column type (provided by `tabularx`) to allow for automatic linebreaking while also making it easy to fit the tabular material into the width of the textblock. If you don't want a `table`-type caption, don't issue a `\caption` instruction inside the `xltabular` environment. The `figure` environment cannot, repeat: *cannot*, span more than one page and is thus not the way to go.

Comment: Alright! Thank you VERY much for your explanation ...and patience ! ;-)